# Combining two pandas dataframes into one based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two dataframes, simplified they look like this:

**Dataframe A**

| ID | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | peach |

**Dataframe B**

| ID | flag | price ($) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | B | 4 |
| 2 | A | 2 |

ID: unique identifier for each item
flag: unique identifier for each vendor
price: varies for each vendor

In this simplified case I want to extract the price values of dataframe B and add them to dataframe A in separate columns depending on their flag value.

The result should look similar to this
**Dataframe C**

| ID | item | price_A | price_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | peach | 2 | 4 |

I tried to split dataframe B into two dataframes the different flag values and merge them afterwards with dataframe A, but there must be an easier solution.

Thank you in advance! :)

*edit: removed the pictures

Comment: Please don't add tables as images. If you can't get the formatting right, someone will gladly edit it for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) Merge the frames, then use groupby.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I've tried splitting dataframe b and merging it into dataframe 1 but it's a quite complicated solution. I thought there must be an easier way to pull the data into one table.
I'll try your approach using group by. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge` and `pd.pivot_table` for this:

```
df_C = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on=['ID']).pivot_table(index=['ID', 'item'], columns='flag', values='price')
df_C.columns = ['price_' + alpha for alpha in df_C.columns]

df_C = df_C.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df_C
   ID   item  price_A  price_B
0   1  apple        3        2
1   2  peach        2        4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(dfb
 .merge(dfa, on="ID")
 .pivot_table(index=['ID', 'item'], columns='flag', values='price ($)')
 .add_prefix("price_")
 .reset_index()
)
```